# What is the use for server-edit (C-x #)

Tags: emacsclient

This is my current Emacs workflow:

```
emacs --daemon
emacsclient -c
```

then editing few files and saving some of them (and keeping some of them unsaved and open on the server for later edit); then deleting the frame with `C-x 5 0` (and later connecting again with `emacsclient -c`).

What is `C-x #` (server-edit) for? what does it do? how it can affect my workflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

emacsclient waits for emacs server. When you do server-edit, the server notifies emacsclient to terminate.

It all depends on what you are going to do. In chrome I use the 'edit with emacs' extension, which uses emacs server to edit fields like these. From emacs I must notify chrome that I am done by calling server-edit. It is only at that moment that the text get pasted back into the input box (and the frame I am using to edit gets killed). Also, when the buffer is saved, chrome updates the edit field. But server-edit kills the frame too.

But from the command line I don't care to call server-edit. I usually create an alias for emacsclient -n (`e='emacsclient -n'` in bash). That way emacsclient does not have to wait for the server. I rarely do server-edit on these buffers.

Comment: Interesting, I am curious how did you setup Google Chrome to edit this post using Emacs?

Comment: I use the "edit with emacs" extension for Chrome.