# What are the differences between multiple ways to "close" an emacsclient?

Tags: emacsclient

As a standalone instance (without daemon mode) I close my `emacs` via `C-x C-c` (`save-buffers-kill-terminal`).

This works also with `emacsclient` and I see no problem about that.

But the manpage of `emacsclient` tells me that I should close a session via `C-x #` (`server-edit`).

And when I start `emacsclient` the minibuffer informs me that `When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0`. Which would be  `delete-frame-functions`.

So I see 3 kinds of "closing". What are the differences and which one should I use?

I have read the documentation of all three functions but I do not understand them. There are some relevant questions and answers to this topic. But I can not bring them together. I assume the reason is that I lack a lot of emacs basic knowledge that would be relevant to understand the answers.

Maybe relevant:

- [What is the use for server-edit (C-x #)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29454/12999)
- [Why emacsclient say to quit with C-x 5 0?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/33589/12999)
- [Emacs Client: difference between C-x k and C-x #](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21317065/4865723)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why emacsclient say to quit with C-x 5 0?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33589/why-emacsclient-say-to-quit-with-c-x-5-0)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317065/emacs-client-difference-between-c-x-k-and-c-x

Comment: Note that buffers can be explicitly associated with clients, usually by specifying their filenames on the command line with `emacsclient FILE1 FILE2 ...`, and therefore telling the server that you are "done" with a given buffer is information that Emacs can act upon.

Comment: `C-x 5 0` is `delete-frame` which "runs `delete-frame-functions` before actually deleting the frame" (from docstring).